# Let R be a commutative ring and let $A$ and $B$ be ideals of $R$. Show that if $A + B = R$, then $AB = A\cap B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $A$ and $B$ be ideals of $R$.

(i) Show that if $A + B = R$, then $AB = A\cap B$

(ii) Now let $R$ be a Euclidean domain. prove that if $AB = A\cap B$, then $A + B = R$

I can define 
$$
A + B = \{ a + b : a\in A; b \in B\}
$$
$$
AB = \{a_1b_1 + \ldots +a_nb_n : n\in \mathbb{N}; a_i\in A; b_j\in B\}
$$
I can only prove that $AB$ is also an ideal in $R$.

Answer (score 2):

It is always true that $\;AB\subset A\cap B\;$ , and

$$A\cap B=(A\cap B)(A+B)=A\cap AB+AB\cap B\subset AB$$

Comment: Quick question: is the identity in the middle equation usually presented that way in commutative algebra, or is it usually a consequence of the fact that PID's have a distributive lattice of ideals? (I can't even remember if PID's have a distributive lattice of ideals, but it sounds right... I thought it might even be true for Dedekind or Prufer domains... any wisdom appreciated :) )

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the middle step? In particular, how do we get from $(A \cap B)A$ to $A \cap AB$? Alternatively, a reference where the relevant results are stated and proved would be invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

For every $t$ $\in$ $A \cap B$, $t=a+b$, $a \in A$ ,$b \in B$.Then we can get $a \in B$ ,$b \in A$ from $t$ $\in$ $ A \cap B$ And $1=c+d$, $c \in A$, $d \in B$. So $t=1t=(c+d)(a+b)=ca+cb+da+db \in AB$.

Comment: How is $ca+cb+da+db\in AB$?